# Enums in delegate method declaration

Tags: ios, objective-c, enums, delegates

I have an `enum` declared in the `.h` file as follows:

```
typedef enum {
   item1 = 0,
   item2,
   item3
} myEnum;
```

I want to use it in a delegate method signature in a view controller as follows:

```
@protocol myClassDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)myDelegateMethod:(enum myEnum)type;
@end
```

I have included the `.h` file in this view controller class.

Autocomplete does not suggest the enum when creating  the above protocol and the compiler complains as well.

It works fine with using `int` instead of the enum in the signature. However, I'd like to know if there is/isn't a way of using the enum or if I'm doing something wrong.

I have gone through many posts but all of them were of normal methods.

**EDIT:**

ViewControllerA.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewControllerB.h"

typedef enum {
   item1 = 0,
   item2,
   item3
} myEnum;

@interface ViewControllerA : UIViewController <myClassDelegate>

@end
```

ViewControllerB.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewControllerA.h"

@protocol myClassDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)myDelegateMethod:(enum myEnum)type; // Autocomplete does not suggest the enums
                                            // Also, x-code gives warning: Declaration of 'enum myEnum' will not be visible outside of this functio
@end

@interface ViewControllerB : UITableViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) id<myClassDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

Comment: Change `(enum myEnum)type` to `(myEnum)type` works for me.

Comment: Already tried, didn't work. Did you use that for delegate method declarations?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't use it for delegate method, will try it later.

Comment: Yeah, my problem is with delegates. Works fine otherwise for me too. Thanks though.

Comment: I just did the same in delegate method, and compiler did not complain.

Comment: Can you show your whole .h files? It's hard to know what you're doing wrong just with that. Also, have a look at: http://nshipster.com/ns_enum-ns_options/ for a more modern way to define enums.

Comment: @gabbler XCode tells me `"Declaration of 'enum myEnum' will not be visible outside of this function"` at the declaration. `"Argument type 'enum myEnum' is incomplete"` at the delegate method call.

Comment: Move the `typedef enum` declaration inside `ViewControllerA.h` and change  `enum myEnum` to `myEnum` in protocol function declaration.

Comment: @gabbler Doing so prevents the enum from being visible in ViewControllerA. However, this could be because A now has started to complain that it `"Cannot find protocol declaration for 'myClassDelegate'"`. Command clicking on the protocol name takes me to the declaration, though. This also happens when using int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a circular header dependency (`ViewControllerA.h` imports `ViewControllerB.h` and vice versa).

Move the `enum` declaration into a common header file and import that wherever it's needed:

CommonTypes.h:

```
typedef enum {
   item1,
   item2,
   item3
} MyEnum;
```

ViewControllerA.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewControllerB.h"

@interface ViewControllerA : UIViewController <myClassDelegate>
// I assume there is a reference to ViewControllerB here somewhere?
@end
```

ViewControllerB.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CommonTypes.h"

@protocol myClassDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)myDelegateMethod:(MyEnum)type;
@end

@interface ViewControllerB : UITableViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) id<myClassDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

Comment: Although this may "solve" the problem, I don't think separating an enum that has a clear association with that class (assuming this is the case) into a "common types" header is a good idea. This is a workaround, not a fix. -- If the circular dependency is the problem, use forward class declarations.

Comment: @KerrM Well it's not clear from the question how closely associated the `enum` is with the view controllers.  If it's not *app global* then a more specific name should be used for the header file name.  However it's not possible for me to know one way or the other.

Comment: The enum is related to the view controller class

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i3g091ar6h27g9h/EnumTest.zip?dl=0) is an example that demonstrate your view controller structure and it worked for me.

Comment: Not a realistic answer as the issue is with a circular dependency in the header files; avoiding header files altogether simply avoids the issue.

Comment: I have heard once Xcode can resolve the circular dependency in the header files and in the project I do `#import "ViewControllerA.h"` in `ViewControllerB`'s implementation file.

Comment: It doesn't unless you use forward class/protocol declarations (i.e. `@class SomeOtherClass;`).  You cannot do it via `#import`.

Comment: That's right, in my case it is different, I didn't need to reference `ViewControllerA` in `ViewControllerB.h`.

Comment: So you agree the root cause is a circular header dependency?

Comment: Yes,  I just tried to replicate the problem, if you import each other in header files, the enum is not visible anymore.

Comment: Thanks guys, it was the circular dependency.